# how insert lookup field in Zoho via PHP-SDK APIv2

Tags: zoho

I try insert record in Calls module, its ok, but when i try insert record linked to Lead or Contacts i get such error -  *Caused by:'required field not found'*

I try add that lookup field such ways:

```
 $record->setFieldValue("What_Id", '"id":"4270452000000312806"');
 $record->setFieldValue("What_Id", '"entityId":"4270452000000312806"');
 $record->setFieldValue("What_Id", '"name":"Markus List"');
 $record->setFieldValue("What_Id", '"entityId":"4270452000000312806", "name":"Markus List"');
 $record->setFieldValue("What_Id", '"id":"4270452000000312806" "name":"Markus List"');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need use field "se_module":

```
$record->setFieldValue("What_Id", "4270452000000312806");/*Contact or Lead ID*/
$record->setFieldValue("Who_Id", "4270452000000242013");/*Company linked to contact*/
$record->setFieldValue("se_module", "Leads");/*Leads or Contacts*/
```

Thans to Dharani form Zoho CRM Support who share with me that info.